# How often to run an air conditioner that is otherwise unused?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have through-the-wall air conditioners that I normally don't run. I live in the tropics, it's warm every day, but we have cooling trade winds and ceiling fans, and it's rarely so hot that I want air conditioning.

I've heard that running the air conditioners occasionally will help keep them in working order for longer. Will they last longer, and why? How often should I run them, and for how long each time?

Comment: Would think about once a month or every two months for 30 to 60 minutes should be okay.

Comment: Humid air contains moisture that tends to cause problems on the electrical-mechanical component if the unit is idled for a long period. I probably would let it run once a week to get rid of the moisture.

Answer (score 1):

Run it as often as you want, I don't think there are rules. When power outage stops our central air, I use a window unit in the bedroom.  Fortunately we do not need it often; maybe 3 times one year and no use the next year. I intend to run it occasionally but I never get around to it. So, it has probably sat for two years, and then been used. There has never been a problem. I have had it about 15 years. It is a low price unit from the big box store.